# Java/Eclipse debugging: Which thread has the debugger's focus?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

I have a Java program developed under Eclipse, which has elaborate features embedded in the program intended to assist debugging.  Now that I am adding threads to the mix, these features need to know which thread I am focusing on in the debugger.

The best I have come up with so far is to add a "focus here" instance variable
to a thread, and manually set it (from the debugger) when I want to direct the
debugging features attention.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hmm, when I do this from another IDE, I set a break point in code, and which thread hits just depends.  Are you trying to stop a specific thread?

Comment: Usually I already have stopped some thread, either at a breakpoint or at a thrown error.  The debugger knows which thread this is but the program GUI, which is still running, does not.

Comment: So your GUI debugger doesn't know which thread is stopped?  I know Netbeans has a debugger which works with threads (and the debugger uses a GUI).  I'd guess Eclipse does the same.  Or I don't understand your comment.  Ask on the Eclipse forum if there's a way to inspect whichever thread(s) are paused by the debugger.

Comment: The debugger is fully aware of what it is doing, but the program being debugged doesn't know what the debugger is doing, and it's desirable that it does.